# jQuery dollar sign is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, yql

In my quest to get historical information, i tried using the below code. Chrome debugger says that `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Can you suggest a fix, i'm really stuck. I just need this to work on Chrome, and I am tapping into YQL and Yahoo API.

here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pCK5q/1/

```
<html>
  <head>      
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        /* historical data code that breaks */
        var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
        var startDate = '2012-01-01';
        var endDate = '2012-01-08';
        var jsonData = encodeURIComponent('select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and startDate = "' + startDate + '" and endDate = "' + endDate + '"');
        $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json", callback);

        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pencils');
        data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
        data.addColumn('string', 'text1');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pens');
        data.addColumn('string', 'title2');
        data.addColumn('string', 'text2');      // not on the fly


        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,2), 14045, undefined, undefined, 20374, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,3), 55022, undefined, undefined, 50766, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,4), 75284, undefined, undefined, 14334, 'Out of Stock','Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,5), 41476, 'Bought Pens','Bought 200k pens', 66467, undefined, undefined],
          [new Date(2008, 1 ,6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined]
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    // Note how you must specify the size of the container element explicitly!
    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery reference?

Comment: Are you importing jquery? or another library that uses $?

Comment: Select 'jQuery' from the dropdown on the left in your JsFiddle. Currently it's Mootools...

Comment: Please learn how to use jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pCK5q/2/. Also, you never define `callback` anywhere.

Comment: @FelixKling, how should i define the `callback` then?

Comment: Well, it's a function that is called when the data was retrieved... I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with the code, so I would just recommend to read the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.

Comment: You know, jsFiddle has a frame called "JavaScript" for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
```

Just under this one you already have:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
```

This will load jQuery from the Google jsapi you already use. This is the best solution regarding your code.

Comment: @bouncingHippo: Well, the error is clear isn't? You are using it in `$.getJSON(...)` but you never define it. We are not a debugging service...

Comment: `callback` is what happens when getJSON is done, replace it by `function(){alert("done!");}`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisG.B. i get a bad request `GET http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=[object%20Object]&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json 400 (Bad Request) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
f.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.getJSON jquery.min.js:4
drawChart`

Comment: Well this is another problem not related to the one you asked help for. The URL youre trying to get information from doesn't work. You should investigate this way...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisG.B. i found the error in the url and i fixed it. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just add a reference to the JQuery source before your script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a jQuery reference:

```
<head>      
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
```

OR (but i thinks this wont work because you are calling a jQuery in your loading function, thus first way is probably better)

Add it via the JSAPI Google Loader you're using:

```
<head>      
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
        google.load("jquery", "1.8.3"); // note, you can also load jQueryUI this way,
```

// on another note, not sure how high a version google supports
Please see [Hosted Libs](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) for more info

Comment: interesting approach...will it prevent `bad GET request`?

Comment: If you load jQuery library first, then `$.getJSON` will work as long as its parameters are established correctly, though honestly, I havn't looked at yours yet, will now ... eh, I don't know about that data line, i usually send data as an object, not a string, but try it! [See example here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#example-0)