# Why do I get "$ is undefined" after using jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery dollar sign is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482022/jquery-dollar-sign-is-undefined)

I want to known Why does `TypeError: $ is undefined` Error Occurs ,
I known the alternative is to use jQuery which solves the problem, why does $ is undefined, even after using correct jQuery plugin.

Can any one Give me the Explanation regarding this , I known the alternative to be used and also why that alternative works . can any one Explain Me Please.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to reference jQuery without including it, hence it is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your intent is to be using the jQuery library when you call `$()`, then `$` is a function normally defined by the jQuery library when it loads.  If that symbol is not defined when you try to use it, then there are these possibilities:

1. You haven't loaded the jQuery library into the page where you're getting this error.
2. You are trying to reference the `$` function before jQuery is loaded in which case you would either need to move the jQuery library earlier in your page or move the offending code after where jQuery is loaded.
3. Some jQuery code has called [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which causes the `$` symbol to be undefined.  In this case, using `jQuery()` will work instead of `$()`.

Answer (score 2):

$ is just a variable pointing jQuery object. Your jQuery library is not having that defined. You can change it to point your object or function. The following example will make `$` point to function `myfun`.

```
$ = myfun;

function myfun()
{
 alert("myfun");
}

$();
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Mpnew/1/)**

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Old
>   references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict()
>   simply restores them.

Comment: i am using the latest jquery plugin 1.8.1-min then also it is giving error, and the variable will be declared in plugin then it should work right.

Comment: If you getting undefined for $, make sure you include the library before you use it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is:

- Either replace the `$` with `jQuery` in the `script which causing the error` or define the `$` to some variable and use it with alternative to this.

i mean Either this way:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('selector').click(function(){
     jQuery('other_selector').hide();
  });
});
```

or this way:

```
var jQ = $;

jQ(document).ready(function(){
  jQ('selector').click(function(){
     jQ('other_selector').hide();
  });
});
```

or there is one more thing use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

`Try this and see if this helps.`

Answer (score -1):

You have to include the jquery file(min.js or jquery-latest.js) on your page